# Body content eaten by navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I have looked for other answers on SO that should answer the question, but I'm having a hard time finding relevant help.

On my webpage, I have two nav bars, one each for the top and bottom. My problem is that my "body" is getting eaten up by the two nav bars. I would prefer to have the content scale to the edges of each nav bar rather than extending into them.

`The sample code can be seen in this fiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/qLjcao3p/

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your content is displaying under the header and footer is because the header and footer have fixed positions. These elements space is not taken into consideration when rendering your page. So the content will be generated as if the nav are not there.

Adding margins as suggested will solve the problem by giving extra white space that will allow you to scroll from beginning to end for your content.

Are you using jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 2):

Adding some margin or padding on the body will help. If that is what you were looking for.

```css
// em or rem values recommended
body {
  margin:60px 0 40px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only to add `margin` to `body` like:

```
body{
   margin : 60px 0; // 60px for top and bottom side and 0 for left and right side
}
```

Try  [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qLjcao3p/1/) example

Answer (score 0):

Add a padding to bottom and top of your container:

```
#bodyContent {
padding:60px 0;
}
```

60px looked fine. That is really the hight of your Nav.